# Finding nil when unwrapping node.name.last()

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am having an Issue with the code below, I desperately need that last letter of the name of the node on which I am pressing.

To do this, I iterate through all the child nodes of my scene until I find one that shares location with my touch point.

Once I have found that, I use a guard state ment :

```
let nodeName = node.name
            guard let letter = nodeName?.last else { return }
```

to find the letter, but the compiler does not continue to run through the functions as it finds nil when trying to pull the last character from the name of the node.

**THANKS A MILLION FOR BEING PATIENT WITH ME AND MY CODE AS I AM A BEGINNER**

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
    let touchPosition = touch.location(in: self)
    guard let scene = scene else { return }

    for node in scene.children {
        if node.frame.contains(touchPosition) && node.name != "background" {
            let nodeName = node.name
            guard let letter = nodeName?.last else { return }
            handleGuess(letter: letter)
            node.removeFromParent()
            if !(lettersToGuess?.contains(letter))! && letter != "1" && letter != "0" {
                currentStep += 1
            } else if letter == "1" {

            } else if letter == "2" {

            } else if letter == "3" {

            } else if letter == "4" {

            }
        }
    }
}

func setupMenu() {      
    // Load Background and place background image
    let backgroundTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "menuBG")
    background.texture = backgroundTexture
    background.zPosition = -1
    background.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX * 0.25, y: frame.midY)
    let bgSizeFactor = backgroundTexture.size().height / frame.size.height
    background.size = CGSize(width: backgroundTexture.size().width / bgSizeFactor , height: frame.size.height)
    addChild(background)

    animateBackground()
    setupRain()

    // TODO: Add Button center screen displaying current level, clicking this will start a new game.
    let playTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "playButton")
    let playButton = SKSpriteNode(texture: playTexture)
    playButton.name = "playbutton2"
    let playButtonFactor = playTexture.size().width / frame.size.width
    playButton.size = CGSize(width: frame.size.width * 0.65, height: (playTexture.size().height / playButtonFactor) * 0.65)
    playButton.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
    playButton.zPosition = 1
    addChild(playButton)

    let rateTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "rateButton")
    let rateButton = SKSpriteNode(texture: rateTexture)
    rateButton.name = "rateButton3"
    rateButton.size = CGSize(width: playButton.size.height * 0.85, height: playButton.size.height * 0.85)
    rateButton.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY - playButton.size.height)
    rateButton.zPosition = 1
    addChild(rateButton)

    let noAdsTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "noAdsButton")
    let noAdsButton = SKSpriteNode(texture: noAdsTexture)
    noAdsButton.name = "noAdsButton4"
    noAdsButton.size = CGSize(width: playButton.size.height * 0.85, height: playButton.size.height * 0.85)
    noAdsButton.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX - playButton.size.height, y: frame.midY - playButton.size.height)
    noAdsButton.zPosition = 1
    addChild(noAdsButton)

    let zapTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "zapButton")
    let zapButton = SKSpriteNode(texture: zapTexture)
    zapButton.name = "zapButton5"
    zapButton.size = CGSize(width: playButton.size.height * 0.85, height: playButton.size.height * 0.85)
    zapButton.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX + playButton.size.height, y: frame.midY - playButton.size.height)
    zapButton.zPosition = 1
    addChild(zapButton)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your below line is the problem

```
guard let letter = nodeName?.last else { return }
```

You are returning here which breaks the for loop and returns from the method.
Instead, try replacing it with below.

```
guard let letter = nodeName?.last else { continue }
```

Above will just continue the loop if the letter is nil for the current node.

Comment: You are a rockstar

Comment: If you don't mind explaining, I just dont understand how it is finding nil because the names for these nodes are set.

Comment: It is hard to tell just by looking at the code but you can debug by printing your node just after the line "for node in scene.children" or by placing breakpoint just as you enter the for loop and then you will be able to see what node you are iterating on. This will give you more idea why that node is not having name.